# Arduino FrSky Telemetry

Tags: arduino, telemetry

I tried to get telemetry data from Naze32 (CleanFlight) via FrSky protocol with an Arduino Uno, but I didn't get any data. 
I used this library:
https://github.com/jcheger/frsky-arduino
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBhft.png)